# Broadcom wireless and Realtec audio driver problem in linux mint 16 petra

Tags: drivers

How can I install my wireless and audio driver in Linux mint using command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Wireless driver:

1. Open Driver manger from Administration
2. Select `bcmwl-kernal-source`
3. Click “Apply changes” (requires a few minutes, depending on your network speed)

Another way to install wireless driver:

You are required to connect to the Internet with the LAN interface before proceeding.

1. After successfully installing LMDE, you have to update it first prior to installing the driver.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. After a successful update, we can now install the desired driver for our Broadcom wireless card:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
   ```

   All you have to do is wait for the installation to finish and you will be able to use the Broadcom wifi card.

Here's an update if you're trying to install the driver on a netbook with low-power b43 chipset:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Updating my LMDE with the latest kernel had my Broadcom wireless messed up. In order to have my connection back, I had to use a different set of commands.

```
sudo -i apt-get install module-assistant wireless-tools broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
m-a a-i broadcom-sta
echo "blacklist brcm80211" >>/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf
update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcm80211
modprobe wl
iwconfig
```